# Crawler image blocked by cors

Tags: jquery, cors, web-crawler, domcrawler

When I scrape data which includes images from other websites, I encounter the following error:

```js
$.get('https://truyenvua.com/128/1081/1.jpg?gt=hdfgdfg', function (data) { console.log(data) });
```

An error occurred as follows.

```
access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://truyenvua.com/128/1081/1.jpg?gt=hdfgdfg' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Please help me with the solution

Comment: don't use a web browser to scrape other web pages.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate of the question from the same author https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76121319/how-to-download-image-blocked-by-cors